# WordPress 6.1.1 does not upload the .WEBP images but with old browser upload does it correct

Tags: images

I have WordPress version 6.1.1 and hello theme version 2.6.1
The issue is weird, from **Dashboard -> Media** I'm not able to upload .WEBP images.
but when I click on *Try the browser uploader instead* it uploads .WEBP file successfully.

but when I try from **multi-file uploader**(which is the default uploader) I got the below error:

`"This image cannot be processed by the web server. Convert it to JPEG or PNG before uploading."`

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/Hy2VBEa2rGoH

after, upload with browser-uploader the .WEBP image appears on media gallery without any issue and I can use the uploaded image in Elementor or anywehere.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: WordPress didn't support .webp natively, because not all browsers can use them (though that's [less true than it used to be](https://caniuse.com/webp)). Normally you'd use a webp plugin to correctly serve webp and not-webp copies of all of your images, but maybe you can get away with just enabling the format nowadays.

Comment: Or are you asking why the inconsistency?